# IOS simulator is black when I load my app

Tags: ios, xcode

My IOS simulator is black when I load my app. My Main Interface is set to the correct storyboard. I have a storyboard entry point setup also.

The home screen works but my app does not. Any suggestions
I have googled but can not find the fix to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Yes 
    "func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  
        return true
    }"

Comment: the initial view controller is a normal view and nothing unusual in the debug window

Comment: Here is my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions functions - func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

Comment: Here is story board setup - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rV0chRXaeLgk2czVgsaihjfd8pZxopWL/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Check if your app is using SceneDelegate class & also check if there exists a AppManifest File in Info.plist .If that's the case you have to provide App's Entry point inside Scene Delegate Class in method.

For Example

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

```
    let initialViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "DatePicker")  as! DatePicker

    let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)

    // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = tabBarCnt
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

}